# Select all images exported into lightroom collection

Tags: lightroom

I need to select all images in a catalog that gave been exported and place them in a collection. The metadata is stored against each image but I can't find how to access it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What "metadata is stored" are you referring to? I don't believe there is going to be a way to select them, but you may be able to create a Smart Collection that would work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by this you mean literally exported, as opposed to being in a published collection (for example to disk). The act of export is stored in the develop history list which is not what is commonly considered metadata.  To my knowledge it is not saved in any regular metadata field that can be searched.  There are a number of plugins that will let you search and select based on metadata that Lightroom does not itself select/search on (for [example](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer)) but I do not believe any of these access the develop history list, at least in a brief search I could not find any.  Further, be aware that the develop history list is not required, can be deleted, and can be lost in certain operations (e.g. writing metadata to xmp side card, and re-importing from it), so it is also possible you have photos exported and no record at all retained.

It would be conceivably possible to build a list of all exports by directly accessing the SQLite database, and thus it should be possible to include this feature in a plugin, if you found a plugin developer interested in doing so. Here is an example statement just for demonstration:

SELECT * FROM Adobe_LibraryimageDevelopHistoryStep where name like '%Export%'  limit 1000

That would need to be joined over several tables, depending on your desired output; the problem is to have that available as a selection or search criteria in Lightroom requires wrapping it up in a plugin, a significant programming task.

If (all of) your exports ended up on a site, such as Smugmug, then some plugins will do a search to sync photos present with your lightroom catalog. The Smugmug plugin does this easily, and I suspect other sites are similar. Thus you could drive it from the other direction -- match uploaded photos to the catalog, which puts them in a published collection, thus indirectly achieving what you want. Obviously that is only viable if your exports went (solely) to a service which supports the sync function.

Bottom line other than niche solutions, or custom database programming, I do not think you can do what you need from within Lightroom or commonly available plugins.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this might be the case - have to dust my SQL skills off!